# How can I get the penultimate element in a list?

Tags: c++, stl, stdlist

I have a `std::list<double> foo;`

I'm using

```
if (foo.size() >= 2){
    double penultimate = *(--foo.rbegin());
}
```

but this always gives me an arbitrary value of `penultimate`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At last, a nicely written question from a new user. Have an upvote!

Comment: For people like me who can't remember what "penultimate" means, it means second-to-last

Comment: @Mehrdad OP definitely does not want that. In particular because that iterator does not point to any element.

Comment: I'll throw in that, unless you know that you specifically need a linked list and can clearly articulate why, don't ever use `std::list`. Prefer `std::vector`.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Rather than *decrementing* `rbegin`, you should increment it, as shown here:<sup>1</sup>

```
double penultimate = *++foo.rbegin();
```

as `rbegin()` returns a *reverse iterator*, so `++` is the operator to move backwards in the container. Note that I've also dropped the superfluous parentheses: that's not to everyone's taste.

Currently the behaviour of your program is *undefined* since you are actually moving to `end()`, and you are not allowed to dereference that. The arbitrary nature of the output is a manifestation of that undefined behaviour.

---

<sup>1</sup>Do retain the minimum size check that you currently have.

Comment: Why can you apply operator++ to a temporary rvalue anyways? I thought ++, --, etc are for lvalues only

Comment: @cat For iterators that allow it, `operator++` is usually a member function, at least to my knowledge.  There's no rule stating that member functions can only be called on lvalues, [unless the member function is ref-qualified as `&`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/888d3b7a1253866b).

Comment: OP is not moving to `foo.end()` which is a perfectly valid iterator (though it cannot be dereferenced), whereas `foo.rbegin()-1` is invalid, even before trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 28):

The clearest way, in my mind, is to use the construct designed for this purpose (C++11):

```
double penultimate = *std::prev(foo.end(), 2)
```

Comment: Clear only if you kept up with all the functions added in C++11, and a good idea if you want to make your code backwards-incompatible ;) I didn't even know `std::prev` exists!

Comment: This is definitely the clearest solution in my opinion, as it involves the fewest number of operator calls and avoids the backwards/forwards confusion of the accepted answer.

Comment: C++11 came out 6 years ago. If the user wants a legacy approach, they should ask for one.

Answer (score 11):

I would just do `*--(--foo.end())`; no need for reverse iterators. It's less confusing too.

Comment: If you are wondering (like I did), it's two decrements as the end iterator points to an imaginary past-the-end element.